# Mapping only some of the attributes of POCO class to database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I am using code first approach in Entity Framework.
I have a poco class that I want to map on a database but I use the same class to bind the data to my UI hence it contains some extra attributes. I want to map some attributes of the class to database but not all of them but I am unable to do that! Any solution

When the class attributes are equal to table column it works completely fine

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should go ahead and read ["How to ask a question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which will help you improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`NotMapped`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set;} 

    [NotMapped]
    public string NotMapped {get;set;}
}
```